Unable to fetch user details from Autodesk Construction Cloud API in Python
I'm working on a Python application that interacts with the Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) API to fetch and display issue data. While I can successfully retrieve the issues, I'm having trouble getting the user details associated with these issues.
Here's what I've tried:

I'm using the following endpoint to fetch issues:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/issues/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/issues

I've attempted to use this endpoint to get user details:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/users/{user_id}

I've also tried:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/users


However, all attempts to fetch user details result in a 403 Forbidden error.
My current scope includes:
data:read data:write account:read account:write user-profile:read project:read
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import requests
def get_user_details(access_token, project_id, user_id):
   url = f"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/projects/{project_id}/users/{user_id}"
headers = {
"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   print(f"User API response for {user_id}:")
   print(response.json())
   return response.json() if response.status_code == 200 else None

This works fine
issues = get_issues(access_token, project_id)
This fails with 403 Forbidden
for issue in issues:
   user_details = get_user_details(access_token, project_id, issue['assignedTo'])

Questions:

Am I using the correct endpoint to fetch user details?
Are there any additional permissions or scopes I need to request?
Is there a different approach I should be taking to get user information in the context of ACC issues?


Are you using the same token to call the 3 endpoints?
If you retrieve the issues successfully, it means the token you are using is a 3-legged token.

GET account users endpoint:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/users
only allows 2-Legged token, 3-legged token will give 403: this what I
suspect is happening.

GET project users/user_id maybe be failing if the user assigned to the issue is no longer a member of the project, hence. 403.

Use the GET project users first to confirm if the assigned user exists int this project before fetching their details


